# char * array not valid anymore when modified from a function (C99)

Tags: arrays, string, c99

In Vulkan, but it is more a c99 problem, I create my extensions list this way :

```
const char *extension_list[7];
uint32_t extension_count = 0;

extension_list[ extension_count++ ] = VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME;
extension_list[ extension_count++ ] = VK_KHR_MAINTENANCE1_EXTENSION_NAME;
```

Then I can call vkCreateDevice with this extensions array and count:

```
VkDeviceCreateInfo desc;
desc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
desc.enabledExtensionCount = extension_count;
desc.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extension_list ;
// (...)
vkCreateDevice( physical_device, &desc, NULL, &vk.device );
```

I need to add others extensions from a function addOtherExt(). (I simplified the code to only shown my problem, but I have severall extensions to add.)

```
  void addOtherExt( const char *list[], uint32_t *count )
  {
    list[ *count ] = VK_KHR_MAINTENANCE1_EXTENSION_NAME;
    *count += 1;
  }
```

Code is the same except the function call :

```
extension_list[ extension_count++ ] = VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME;
addOtherExt( extension_list, &extension_count );
```

vkCreateDevice doesn't return an error, but I got a crash with message "Failed to find entrypoint vkAcquireNextImageKHR".

I print the array extension_list and it's look exactly like in version without function (extension is added), and the extension_count is correct.
I have suspected the terminating '\0' but did not manage to make it work.

Comment: My C is really rusty, but I think `*count++` isn't doing what you think it's doing.  It is incrementing the address of count, not the de-referenced value.  There's probably a more elegant way to say it, but `list[*count]; *count += 1;` would be safe and readable.

Comment: OK, thx. It was just a simplification mistake. I do a *count += 1; in my function. I modified my question.

Comment: There is probably a bug in the large amount of code you aren't showing.  Either that, or your Vulkan implementation just doesn't work when you enable both of those extensions at the same time.  Or maybe the order of the extensions matters.

Comment: If you can verify that adding the extension without a function call works, then you can compare your working code and your non-working code and try to make them closer one step at a time.